# How Rust determines which lifetime is longer

Tags: rust

```
 struct A<'a, 'b> {
    field: &'a B<'b>,
}
```

Rust expects `'a` last longer than `'b`, why it is the case?
Should not `'b` lasts longer than `'a`, since B needs to be valid as long as `field` is valid.

Comment: *"Rust expects `'a` last longer than `'b`"* - source? Your intuition is correct, what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @ChrisBeck shouldn't be necessary in this case. This Q&A may help you and OP: [Does `&'a T` imply `T: 'a`?](/q/77025320/2189130)